# VBA Compare rows in two worksheets and add missing data

Tags: vba, for-loop, compare

I would like to compare two exact worksheets that are stored in two different workbooks.

I would like data from 1st sheet (see column with blue ID - KDws) appear in the 2nd sheet (green ID - KDwsMain), which is the main file. Wouldn't like for the duplicates to show in the main file.

Any ideas how to improve the code below?

[image]
[image]

My piece of code:

```
Sub CompareKDandDetailsView()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wbMain As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim LastR As Long, LastR_main As Long
Dim i As Integer, k As Integer, j As Integer

Dim KDws As Worksheet, KDwsMain As Worksheet
Dim strFile As String
  
Set KDws = wb.Worksheets("KD")
LastR = KDws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'open Target file
MsgBox "Select the main file to upload your changes."
strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Workbooks.Open (strFile)

Set KDwsMain = wbMain.Worksheets("KD")
LastR_main = KDwsMain.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'-----------------------------

'-----------------------------
k = KDwsMain.UsedRange.Rows.Count 'last used row of the first worksheet
j = KDws.UsedRange.Rows.Count 'last used row of the second worksheet

For i = 2 To k 'Loop through the used rows of the first worksheet
    'use "countIf" to quickly check if the value exists in the given range
    'This way we don't have to loop through the second worksheet each time
     If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(KDwsMain.Range(KDwsMain.Cells(2, 1), KDwsMain.Cells(j, 1)), KDws.Cells(i, 1).Value) > 0 Then
        'do nothing
    Else
        LastR_main = KDwsMain.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        KDwsMain.Cells(LastR_main + 1, 1).Value = KDws.Cells(i, 1)
        KDwsMain.Cells(LastR_main + 1, 2).Value = KDws.Cells(i, 2)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What "exact worksheets" does mean, if you say that duplicates may be possible? Do you want doing the processing only for columns A:A, or A:A should be considered as reference to mach the two sheets and processing will be done on the rows having the same reference? Which of them is the "main file"? I mean, looking to your pictures. If they must have some relevance...

Comment: So, you like to add on the first empty row of the second sheet the values form A:B range of the first one, if the value in A:A first workbook is not found in  the second one. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: So I have two worksheets - in the code it is KDws and KDwsMain. I want KDwsMain sheet to include all IDs that are in KDws sheet. So if you loop through KDws rows, the first one that we are interested in is Base Pay (in the screenshots) and I want it to be pasted to last available row in KDwsMain sheet.

Comment: Does the row to be pasted have more then two columns?  I can see in your code only two...

Comment: Yes, it does - it has 12 columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please. Not tested, but I think it should work:

```
Sub CompareKDandDetailsView()
Dim wb As Workbook, wbMain As Workbook

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim LastR As Long, LastR_main As Long, lastCol As Long
Dim i As Long

Dim KDws As Worksheet, KDwsMain As Worksheet
Dim strFile As String
  
Set KDws = wb.Worksheets("KD")
LastR = KDws.cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastCol = KDws.cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'open Target file
MsgBox "Select the main file to upload your changes."
strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Set wbMain = Workbooks.Open(strFile)

Set KDwsMain = wbMain.Worksheets("KD")
'-----------------------------

 For i = 2 To LastR 'Loop through the used rows of the first worksheet
    'use "countIf" to quickly check if the value exists in the given range
    'This way we don't have to loop through the second worksheet each time
     LastR_main = KDwsMain.cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
     If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(KDwsMain.Range("A2:A" & LastR_main), _
                                                       KDws.Range("A" & i)) = 0 Then

        KDwsMain.Range(KDwsMain.cells(LastR_main, "A"), KDwsMain.cells(LastR_main, lastCol)).Value = _
                                            KDws.Range(KDws.cells(i, 1), KDws.cells(i, lastCol)).Value
    End If
 Next i
End Sub
```